# Where to find good Dynamixel models (license)?

Tags: ros, cad

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a package containing dynamixel models already?
Or does anybody know if I can get the models under BSD
or similar license (GPL ...) to add it to my package (robot file)?

Regards,

Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215215/where-to-find-good-dynamixel-models-(license)?/) by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know how they are licensed, but CAD files are available at http://en.robotis.com/BlueAD/board.php?bbs_id=downloads&mode=view&bbs_no=26324&page=1&key=&keyword=&sort=&scate=DRAWING.

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 792 on 2015-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-08-05**:
Thanks, I guess I need to check for the license ... or ask for it.